# Get property of object by another value inside same object

Tags: ruby

Here is the output of `something.to_yaml`:

```
name: test
id: 1
--
name: bobo
id: 2
--
(...)
```

I want to get the id that is the partner of a given name in `something { }`. If the name is `"test"`, I want to get `"1"`; something like: do `something[test]`, and retrieve `1`. What is the cleanest way of doing this in ruby? I can only think of populating my code with loops and I didn't want to, unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Why are you doing it in YAML? You better do it in Ruby.

Comment: @sawa I am. I'm just outputing as yaml x)

Comment: Why? Why don't you show it to us as a Ruby object?

Comment: @sawa Why not? Better yet, how exactly does that influence my question? Could you please help me where I need? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `something`(before it's output to YAML) is an array of hashes.  In which case

```
something.select{|a|a["name"]=="test"}.first["id"]
```

It would be easier if you showed the original object instead of the YAML representation.